# Declaring a template struct with no arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have this implementation of a list:

```
template<typename T, typename... TT>
struct List {
    typedef T head;
    typedef List<TT...> next;
    enum { size = sizeof...(TT)+1 };
};

template<typename T>
struct List<T> {
    typedef T head;
    typedef NIL next;
    enum { size = 1 };
};
```

I'm trying to add this:

```
template <>
struct List {
    typedef NIL head;
    enum { size = 0 };
};
```

So that I can declare an empty list like:

```
List<>
```

When I try to add this I get the error:

```
error: explicit specialization of non-template 'List'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: `template <> struct List<>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to your main template a default value, I changed NIL for void in the below example, but it works for any type.

```
template<typename T = void, typename... TT>
struct List
{
  typedef T head;
  typedef List<TT...> next;
  enum { size = sizeof...(TT)+1 };
};

template<typename T>
struct List<T>
{
  typedef T head;
  typedef void next;
  enum { size = 1 };
};

template<>
struct List<>
{
  typedef void head;
  enum { size = 0 };
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was missing!

Answer (score 4):

Your primary template should then be:

```
template<typename ... Ts> struct List;
```

and you can then partial specialize for 0, 1, N arguments.